# Does e language provides a more efficient solution or data structure for dealing with FIFO management?

Tags: specman, e

I am extensively using lists in our UVC’s monitor, due to our protocol specifications a lot is modeled using FIFO operation of `list.push()` and `list.pop0()`, since `pop0()` is a very expansive operation in ‘e’ on large list,

Does e language provides a more efficient solution or data structure for dealing with FIFO management?

Answer (score 1):

You can use eTL.
these are templates that implements common cases such as FIFO and more.
the way they are implemented is more efficient and focus on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use etl. For example,  in order to overcome the poor performance of the list.pop0() function, you can use a deque of uint (instead of list of uint) for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes e support solution for dealing with those kinds of problems. 
One of the solutions is using eTL or redefine existing methods.